# Find the minimum value of the perimeter

Tags: optimization, area, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Find the minimum value of the perimeter of a triangle whose area is 3 $cm^2$
I tried it using Hero rule 
$$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
$$9 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$
But it did not serve me well ?

Comment: Indeed; so, try to prove that the minimum is obtained when the triangle is equilateral. Geometric reasoning may serve you better than Heron's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM and by your work we obtain:
$$9=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\leq s\left(\frac{s-a+s-b+s-c}{3}\right)^3=\frac{s^4}{27}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: How did you get the last equality to $\frac{s^4}{27}$?

Comment: @Don Draper Because $s-a+s-b+s-c=3s-(a+b+c)=3s-2s=s.$

Comment: Sorry, at first I didn't notice that $s$ doesn't stand  for the triangle area.